# Angular - Reset <select><option> selection if I choose not to accept change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown list made of `<select>` and `<option>` tags, with a function to bring up a confirmation box when a selection is made. A simple `yes`/`no`.

Clicking `yes` will set the current state to the state chosen from the dropdown, whereas `no` will of course not change the state.

However, when clicking `no`, the dropdown list will remain highlighted on the state that we just declined changing to.

Is there a way in which I can get it to go back to the current state?

[Here is my stackblitz to show what is going on](https://stackblitz.com/edit/option-reset)

### UPDATE

Some of the answers below have been good, but the one thing missing from them is that, if the `state` is not assigned to a value, I do not get the `disabled` option displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold prevois selected option in a variable `preState` and revert `newState` to `preState` when user clicks no.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  state;
  newState;
  preState;
  checkState = false;

  options = [
    {name:'dormant'}, 
    {name:'active'}, 
    {name:'finished'}
  ];

  setState(state) {
    this.preState = this.newState;
    this.newState = state
    this.checkState = true;
  }

  selectedOption(option) {
    return this.newState === option;
  }

  yes() {
    this.state = this.newState;
    this.checkState = false;
  }

  no() {
    this.checkState = false;
    this.newState = this.preState;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To show the disabled option mentioned in your UPDATE, put `[selected]='!newState'` on the disabled option:

```
<select (change)="setState($event.target.value)">
  <option disabled [selected]='!newState'>--Pick an option--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.name" [selected]="selectedOption(option.name)">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="checkState" class="check-state">
  <p>Are you sure you want to change</p>
  <p><span class="bold">{{state}}</span> to <span class="bold">{{newState}}</span></p>
  <button (click)="yes()">yes</button><button (click)="no()">no</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: i added the considerations needed for your update

Answer (score 1):

Switch to reactive forms and register the default state.

You can then call `reset` on your form control with the default state.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/option-reset-hfsn6m?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```html
<select [formControl]="select">
  <option disabled>--Pick an option--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.name" [selected]="selectedOption(option.name)">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
select: FormControl = new FormControl(this.options[0].name);
defaultState = this.select.value;

constructor() {
  this.select.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.setState(value));
}

...

no() {
  this.select.reset(this.defaultState);
  this.checkState = false;
}
```

*N.B. :* I used a form control, but the same applies to form groups

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: You don't have any `disabled` in your code, and even if you did, my solution would take care of it (form controls have a `disabled` property)

Comment: the line `select: FormControl = new FormControl(this.options[0].name);` makes it default to an entry within the array. The `disabled` is in the first `<option>` tag

Comment: Because that's an example. You can put whatever you want as the default value. I chose the first option it is usually what people do (even you, the first option is selected in your example), but you can put whatever you want in it. The beauty of my solution is that whatever the first value is, resetting the control will always set it back.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using two way binding the change you make to your variable doesn't affect the template. This is my approach:

> HTML file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="state" (change)="setState()">
  <option disabled [value]="null">--Pick an option--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.name" >{{option.name}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="checkState" class="check-state">
    <p>Are you sure you want to change</p>
    <p><span class="bold">{{lastState}}</span> to <span class="bold">{{state}}</span></p>
    <button (click)="yes()">yes</button><button (click)="no()">no</button>
</div>
```

> TS File

```
  state;
  lastState;
  checkState = false;

  options = [
    {name:'dormant'}, 
    {name:'active'}, 
    {name:'finished'}
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.lastState = this.state;    
  }

  setState() {
    this.checkState = true;
  }

  yes() {
    this.checkState = false;
    this.lastState = this.state;    
  }

  no() {
    this.checkState = false;
    this.state = this.lastState;
  }
```

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @physicsboy one thing you can do is put null as the disabled option's value, then if your state is null you'll see the disabled option